# Catch every exception of program?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception

I've a WPF application which runs globally fine. But sometimes, the client tell me that he gots some crashes. But I've no information about what happened except what he does.

Is there a way to put a global try{}catch(Exception){LOGEXCEPTION; throw;} somewhere to receive all exceptions generated by a GUI action, or any other option.

Something like a "Last remedy" to log exception that we didn't manage well?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

By handling the following events, you should be able to catch the vast majority (if not all) unhandled exceptions in your application:

- `Application.DispatcherUnhandledException`
- `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`